# Unable to create 4.3 OpenGL context

Tags: c++, opengl, gpu

When I try to run my program, it shows up the message "Unable to create 4.3 OpenGL context." According to the [link](http://openglbook.com/unable-to-create-opengl-4-0-context-flags-n-profile-n/), the information implies that it is the hardware problem.

However, 
my GPU is HD7670M and I check it from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_7000_Series), it supports OpenGL 4.3.

So I want to ask do you know what is coming on? Or can I change the OpenGL version through "glutInitContextVersion" function? I would greatly appreciate for any help you can offer.

Comment: Your GPU supporting it doesn't really matter, its whether your driver supports it.

Answer (score 3):

AMD only has [*beta* support](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-8WINBetaDriver.aspx) for OpenGL 4.3 at present. So unless you're using beta drivers on that hardware, you can't create a 4.3 context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you read that Wiki wrong. The 7670 supports 4.3, but the 7670M only supports 4.2.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right. I think I will use glutInitContextVersion(4,2) to change my OpenGL version.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting the following lines of code in your program if present
Then it must work
`//glutInitContextVersion(4, 3); //glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE);`
For me it worked.